# NO USB detected on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, lsusb

I am new to linux system and encountered several frustrated issues. Trying to list usb devices connected to my system and see what name /port is associated to each bus, and as i have seen many post where showing a list of usb buses on their system.
cmd>ver
Windows Version is Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.153]

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS , WSL2.

$lsusb  ............... no output

$ dmesg ................... [    0.020118]  Microsoft 4.4.0-19041.1-Microsoft 4.4.35

the usb stick is listed in device manager under windows and works normally.

any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be running Ubuntu under WSL.
You Linux installation is running in a Virtual Machine environment in that case.
And because of that it doesn't see the real hardware, but a simulated hardware that doesn't include the USB devices.

You can manually mount the filesystem on the USB stick if you want.

1. Make a mount point folder:  `mkdir /mnt/e`
2. Mount the file system:    `mount -t drvfs e: /mnt/e`

You can also mount a network-share that way: Simply replace `e:` with the UNC path of he share (e.g `\\servername\sharename`

**Please note that the above is WSL specific and has nothing to do with normal Linux operation.**

Comment: My problems is the  wsl2 does not detect any usb  I cant communicate with any device over usb . take look at  https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/issues/81